# Does chrome have a timeout for which form POSTs are cancelled?

Tags: http, google-chrome, timeout

I have a request from a form submitted with a hidden iframe target (it downloads a file as a result).

The serverside handling of this request is complex and can take a while.

When the request takes > 80 seconds or so I see in devtools that it gets cancelled (presumably by the browser).

Does anyone know if chrome has a built-in request timeout limit and if there's any way to force form submissions to use a greater one?

Comment: Ajax won't reliably trigger a download and there are other concerns as well (for example I'm sending a very large xml payload)

Comment: i've seen some issues with this, and it looks like most people recommend using json instead of xml for large files.

Comment: @nathanhayfield yes but the data I'm sending IS xml data (the contents of rendered iframes which get built up on the client). So this isn't a matter of xml-cruft overhead, its more that there just is a lot of data.